# pass string into function as 2 or more arguments

Tags: php, arguments

Hello im just testing things to understand concepts

im trying to do this :

```
$args = "'file.txt', 'w'";
fopen($args);
```

but fopen sees it as one arguments

what am i missing ?

Comment: You can't do that, the proper way to do it would be to use two variables

Comment: do you have a particular reason why would you want to do that?

Comment: The other (ugly) option would be something like `call_user_func_array(fopen, array('file.txt','w'))`

Comment: @Ghost:I sad it , im just testing stuff to understand new concepts...

Comment: Maybe u could use an array and then something like 
    fopen($args[0],$args[1]);

Comment: @adeneo that will do it thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP 5.6 you can use [argument unpacking](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/argument_unpacking) which in my opinion is closest to what you tried:

```
$args = ['file.txt', 'w'];
fopen(...$args);
```

Comment: Well I don't think OP wants to rewrite the `fopen()` function and compile it again

Comment: This works out of the box, tested with PHP 5.6.3 (Windows) and 5.6.6 (Linux). Also see http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php

Comment: You're right! Didn't know they changed/upgraded the functions in php 5.6.6 (I wonder if they did it with all functions, have to test that :D)

Answer (score 1):

What you do is creating one string that is "'file.txt', 'w'" and submit that as ONE argument.

See the method signature of [`fopen()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php):

> fopen ( string $filename , string $mode [, bool $use_include_path = false [, resource $context ]] )

What you want to do is:

```
$file = 'file.txt';
$mode = 'w';
fopen($file, $mode);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're opening a file to so some writing to it, why not use `file_put_contents` - it might be easier to use.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass the arguments like this. A way to do this would be the following:

```
<?
$args = array("file.txt","w");
$fopen($args[0],$args[1]);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should put 2 parameters in fopen()

```
<?
$args = array("file"   => "file.txt",
              "option" => "w");

fopen($args["file"],$args["option"]);
?>
```